# About Solaris translators Jasiensko (French), Kilmartin and Cox

Tags: translation, polish-language, stanislaw-lem, solaris

I am looking for an account of, or historical information about: Jean-Michel Jasiensko's Polish-French translation of Solaris. Particularly, why did he vary the text?

Also, Joanna Kilmartin and Steve Cox's collaborative French-English translation. How did it work? Why was Cox involved? Faber is silent. I know that Jasiensko was a busy translator. Kilmartin is always called "distinguished" and was likewise productive, but, beyond the Times obit, there is nothing online. 'Steve Cox' is a common name - it turns out. Is he still around? So: Maybe a link to some obscure online data? And I'm happy to hear informed conjecture.
(I am well up on this, so I DON'T need other, easily-found material, thanks.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. This site is a bit different from a forum, so we have certain rules here that may sound unusual. For example, your question asks about two translations that appear to be unrelated (other than being translations of the same work). This results in two questions and we would like these questions to be posted separately. So could you please move the question about one of the translations to a different post? Thanks in advance.